# Summarizing each subgroup in Group Footer - Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to work on a report for a client. Basically I need something like such

Group 1: Customer ID
Group 2: Truck ID

```
CustID    Vehicle ID    Detention Time
------    ----------    --------------
   ABX           100                60
                                    35
                                    20
                            TOTAL: 115

                 200                80
                                    15
                            TOTAL:  95

                 300                10
                            TOTAL:  10

TOTALS FOR CUSTOMER ABX
    100    115
    200     95
    300     10
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this without a subreport? I was hoping for a "summary field" that I could summarize more than just a single value.

Thanks!

(FYI using Crystal Reports 2008)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a crosstab; place it in the report-footer section.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, while it was ugly it worked for the client, at least... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to do this, but the one that comes to mind is to use two arrays: One to store the truck ID and another to store the corresponding total. In each inner grouping (TruckID), just tack on another array element and store its total time. To display, you could cast the values to strings, attach a newline character after each entry, and set the field to "Can Grow". So altogether, you'd need three formulas: one to initialize the arrays (in GH1), one to update the arrays with `sum({truck.time},{truck.ID})` (in GF2), and one to display each entry (in GF1).

With that being said, CR has terrible support for containers... You're limited to 1-dimensional, non-dynamic arrays that are gimped at 1000 items max. It doesn't sound like these would be big problems for what you're trying to do, but you will need to `redim preserve` the arrays unless you know ahead of time how many trucks you'll have per customer.

Comment: Bah - yeah I've worked in arrays since this and it's been horrible. Crosstab was the (ugly) way to go. Thanks though!